# Combine positive and negative power supply

Tags: power-supply

I have a DC Motor requiring 24V to run. Does connecting it to +12 and -12 work, as the voltage difference is 24V?

Comment: Obviously, *both* supplies need to be able to handle the full current required by the motor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the voltage across is the potential difference.
Potential +V = 12
Potential -V = -12

Voltage Output: (+V - -V) = 24

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The motor will only see the voltage applied accross it regardless of the what you consider your zero volt reference.